# error on creating folder in AppHarbor

Tags: c#, asp.net, appharbor

i am trying to create a folder using

`Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate));`

i get Access is Denied error.

no problem in localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have file system write access enabled in your AppHarbor application?

[image]

I think you also need to do a re-deploy of your application after enabling it, but not 100% sure.

**UPDATE:** Based on the poster's response, yes you do have to do a re-deploy after enabling this option.

Comment: yep that was it. didn't know there was an option there. thanks.

Comment: as a note: i had to redeploy the thing.